# Can't SSH to GCloud after editing /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, ssh, interface, virtual-machine, gcloud

After editing /etc/network/interfaces on a GCloud VM instance I cannot access the machine at all through SSH. GCloud SDK shell still shows the instance running but the applications are no longer available. I have tried to SFTP to the machine as well, but without success. Is there any way to edit/repair the VM instance interfaces file without having to revert back to an earlier snapshot?

Many thanks!

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general server/networking tech support.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new GCE instance and attach the disk of the old instance to the new instance. Then you can connect to the new instance and change anything you want in the old disk.

Comment: Thanks Valentin, your answer is helpful. The problem also occurs on the new instance as it's still using the bad /etc/network/interfaces file. There seems to be other solutions involving addAccessConfig and copy-files, but the GCE SDK shell looks like it can't connect either. I'd appreciate if you have any other ideas.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what's going on. Creating a new instance with a new disk should not use the same  /etc/network/interfaces file.
Once the new instance is created and booting, you can attach another disk to it. You can thus attach the second disk, from the previous instance and modify the file.